# How to show that the set of complete lattice congruences of an complete lattice is again complete lattice?

Tags: representation-theory, equivalence-relations, lattice-orders, congruence-relations

Thank you for your help.

I am now trying to understand that the set of complete lattice congruences of a complete lattice is again complete lattice.

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a complete lattice. An equivalence relation $\theta$ of $\mathcal{L}$ is called a **complete lattice congruence** if $(x_i, y_i)\in \theta$ for all $i\in I$ ($I$ is not necessary finite) then $(\vee\{x_i\}, \vee\{y_i\})$ and $(\wedge\{x_i\}, \wedge\{y_i\})$ belong to $\theta$.

We denote by $\mathsf{Con^c}(\mathcal{L})$ the set of all complete lattice congruences of $\mathcal{L}$.

Then, *the set is $\mathsf{Con^c}(\mathcal{L})$ is a complete lattice.*

How to show this?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $L^2$ is a complete congruence of $L$.
So it's enough to show that $\theta = \bigcap_{I\in I}\theta_i$ is a complete congruence, whenever each of the $\theta_i$ is.

Let $(a_j,b_j) \in \theta$, for all $j \in J$.
Let $a^+ = \bigvee_j a_j$ and $b^+ = \bigvee_j b_j$,
and $a_- = \bigwedge_j a_j$ and $b_- = \bigwedge_j b_j$.
Then $(a^+, b^+), (a_-, b_-) \in \theta_i$, for all $i \in I$, because $\theta_i$ is complete.
It follows that $(a^+,b^+), (a_-, b_-) \in \theta$.

Hence $\theta$ is a complete congruence relation of $L$, and the lattice of complete congruences of $L$ is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I have a question. Why it is enough to show $\theta$ is complete congruence?

Since the set  $\mathsf{Con^c}(\mathcal{L})$ is a subset of all equivalences on $\mathcal{L}$, say $\mathsf{Eq}(\mathcal{L})$, I tried $\mathsf{Con^c}(\mathcal{L})$ is a sublattice of $\mathsf{Eq}(\mathcal{L})$.

To show $\mathsf{Con^c}(\mathcal{L})$ is lattice,  I have to show that $\theta_1\vee\theta_2\in\mathsf{Con^c}(\mathcal{L})$. 

However, I do not understand why $(a^{+}, b^{+})\in\theta_1\vee\theta_2$ and $(a^{-}, b^{-})\in \theta_1\vee\theta_2$.

Comment: @sola For a poset to be a complete lattice, it is enough that it is closed under arbitrary meets (including the empty meet, which gives the greatest element). An equivalent way is to prove that it is closed under arbitrary joins. In this case, since the meet is given by intersections, it's easier much easier to use that characterization.

Comment: @sola For a reference on the mentioned result (which you might not know), check [this book](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf), chapter I, Theorem 4.2.